# [закрыто] Конвертация html в swf

Tags: анимация, конвертация, flash, swf

Доброго дня.

Нашёл в Интернете онлайн-генератор баннера. Создал нужный мне баннер с анимацией и текстом. Предложило сохранить в html со всем содержимым.

**Вот скриншот структуры содержимого:**

[image]

Как теперь это содержимое скомпилировать/собрать/преобразовать в один файл формата swf, ну или gif? Или это невозможно?

*Почему сохранил при экспорте не в swf? Потому что буржуйские генераторы баннеров требуют платить кругленькую сумму денег для экспорта в swf, что совсем нерационально для одного некоммерческого баннера.*

Answer (score 2):

Всё оказалось настолько просто, что меня переполняет гордость, что я сам до такого додумался прогулявшись 15 минут на свежем воздухе)

Если кому пригодится - ответ очень прост.
Берете любой захватчик gif анимации с экрана и записываете.
Всё гениально и просто)
И не нужно платить бешеные бабки за один маленький баннер)